# What is Unknown Type in TypeScript + Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, monaco-editor

I've been trying to integrate [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) to one of my web apps. My app is an Angular application and I used [ngx-monaco-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor) wrapper for this.

It works fine in the development environment but when I run the build it fails saying,

```
PS D:\MyApp> ng build --prod
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.6) is greater than your local
version (6.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Date: 2019-10-16T10:08:16.025Z
Hash: 2aabd42f82f1dbf9374b
Time: 14410ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.5f861f4882ecef30cbaa.js (scripts) 319 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.16825ef8af0f92360bac.css (styles) 203 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.e7f5364b276024e19b0b.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.0594610c91de797f492a.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/lib/config.d.ts(2,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
```

Here's `config.d.ts` file content.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export declare const NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG: InjectionToken<unknown>;
export interface NgxMonacoEditorConfig {
    baseUrl?: string;
    defaultOptions?: {
        [key: string]: any;
    };
    onMonacoLoad?: Function;
}
```

I couldn't find this `unknown` type definition in the source. And it is the type that is causing the error.

Here's my the `package.json` file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.3",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.7.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formBuilder": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-click-to-edit": "0.0.7",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6"
  }
}
```

Is it a type available in js/ts by default?
Can anyone tell me how get this fixed?

Comment: `InjectionToken<unknown>` ? try using  `InjectionToken<any>` or this could help you : https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/539#issuecomment-409133513

Comment: Can you show me your config.ts  and your package.json ? `Unknow` should not be Unknow, your error is because a Typing is missing or a lib is not properly installed on prod mode. May be a package oinly installed on devDependancies needed on Dependancies.

Comment: @JoelJoseph Tried it. Giving me long list errors. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @Yvan I added the package.json as a edit. Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Installing package `ngx-monaco-editor@6.0.0` with `ngx-monaco-editor` fixed the issue for me.

```
npm install ngx-monaco-editor --save
npm install ngx-monaco-editor@6.0.0 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a config for monaco and use it as a provider :

This is the EditorConfig

```
const monacoEditorConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
    onMonacoLoad,
    baseUrl: './assets'
};
```

And the way of using it in your module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EditorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MonacoEditorModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: NGX_MONACO_EDITOR_CONFIG, useValue: monacoEditorConfig }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Tried it now. Didn't work. Also the error "Cannot find name 'unknown'" came only in the prod build before. but now it comes when i run in the dev mode as well. Any idea?

Comment: Can you paste your module.ts ?

Comment: Actually installing package ngx-monaco-editor@6.0.0 fixed the issue for some reason. :) Thanks!